# Possible to use translate twice on same element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I used Javascript to translate via transform a circle from the center of the canvas to the upper left. What I want to do next is call a function that picks random coordinates within the canvas and sends them to translate, so its position can be shifted. Unfortunately this is not working.

Can you only call translate once on an element within CSS? This is the conclusion I'm coming to but I haven't been able to find information in the docs say this type of behavior *isn't* allowed.

The heart of the matter:

```
function change_level() {
  var level = document.getElementById("level");
  level.parentNode.removeChild(level);
  var ball = document.getElementById("init_pos");
  ball.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  ball.style.borderRadius = "25px";
  ball.style.transform = "translate(-600%, -647%)";
  setTimeout(ball_movement(ball), 3000);
  ball.style.transition = "background-color 2s ease-in, transform 3s ease";

}

function ball_movement(ball) {
  var movements = 5;
  var x;
  var y;
  for (var i = 0; i < movements; i++) {
    x = getRandomArbitrary(-800, 800);
    y = getRandomArbitrary(-800, 800);
    ball.style.transform = "translate("+x+", "+y+")";
    ball.style.transition = "transform 3s ease";
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Posted my code on jsfiddle, though my calculations are bigger than the campus in jsfiddle and so don't work properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/2c5gwbcd/

Comment: `setTimeout(ball_movement(ball), 3000);` Common mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of corrections needed to your code:

- When setting the `transform` value within `ball_movement`, the `x` and `y` variables have merely numbers as value but the `translate` function needs a value with units (percentage, pixels etc). So, add it by appending `px` or `%` to the string as appropriate.
- In the `timeout` function call, when you give the first param as `ball_movement(ball)` the function gets called immediately. You should wrap it within an anonymous function.

**Note:** In the below snippet, I had reduced the initial value of the `translate` function and the input for the random number calculation to keep the ball movement within boundaries.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var
    html_display = {
      0: "Level One",
      1: "Level Two",
      2: "Level Three",
      3: "Level Four",
      4: "Level Five"
    };

  html_key = 0;

  //need to take level offscreen, add ball
  function change_level() {
    var level = document.getElementById("level");
    level.parentNode.removeChild(level);
    var ball = document.getElementById("init_pos");
    ball.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    ball.style.borderRadius = "25px";
    ball.style.transform = "translate(-150%, -150%)";
    ball.style.transition = "background-color 2s ease-in, transform 3s ease";
    setTimeout(function() {
      ball_movement(ball);
    }, 3000);

  }

  function ball_movement(ball) {
    var movements = 5;
    var x;
    var y;
    for (var i = 0; i < movements; i++) {
      x = getRandomArbitrary(-100, 100);
      y = getRandomArbitrary(-100, 100);
      ball.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
      ball.style.transition = "transform 3s ease";
    }

  }

  function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function intro_html() {
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = html_display[html_key];
    setTimeout(change_level, 1000);
  }

  intro_html();
}
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#level {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#init_pos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  left: 48.17%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 1100px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="level"></p>
  <p id="init_pos"></p>
</div>
```